# to get to the column name or column count in result set of query?

Tags: android, sqlite, select, join

1. SQL:

   ```
   select a.a, a.b, b.c from a, b where a.a=b.a;
   ```
2. SQL:

   ```
   select '*' from table;
   ```
3. SQL:

   ```
   select '*' from table1, table2 where table1.a=table2.a;
   ```
4. SQL:

   ```
   select '*' from table1 left join table2 on table1.a=table2.a;
   ```

Case 1 is knew the column name in result set of sql (OK).
Case 2 is possible find column name (use to `pragma table_info (table);`) (OK).
But case 3, 4 is how to get to the column name of column count in result set?

Comment: If you just want to see the result set simply call DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor()

Answer (score 1):

You can traverse the returned `Cursor` like this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getColumnCount(); i++) {
      Log.d("tag", cursor.getColumnName(i) + " -> " + cursor.getType(i));
 }
```

Note that the cursor.getType() will be one of the following:

```
static final int FIELD_TYPE_NULL = 0;
static final int FIELD_TYPE_INTEGER = 1;
static final int FIELD_TYPE_FLOAT = 2;
static final int FIELD_TYPE_STRING = 3;
static final int FIELD_TYPE_BLOB = 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

A query returns a `Cursor` and you can get cursor column names with e.g. [`getColumnName()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getColumnName(int)).